# (C#) Selenium: How do I choose an option within a ComboBox?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver-c#

How do I select the "C" option of my ComboBox "opcao_pesquisa"?

```html
<form name="Form1" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="operacao" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="d" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="equipe" value="">
    <input type="text" name="conteudo" maxlength="200" size="20" onkeyup="escolhe_opcao_pesquisa(this);">
    <select name="opcao_pesquisa">
        <option value="A">Ambiente</option>
        <option value="C">CNPJ</option>         
        <option value="E" selected="">Nome do Portal</option>
        <option value="P">Número do Portal</option>
        <option value="R">Rede</option>
        <option value="L">Release</option>
        <option value="S">Sufixo Login</option>         
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar &gt;">
</form>
```

I tried the following code:

```c#
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@opcao_pesquisa']"))).SelectByValue("C");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is syntax error in your xPath expression, an opening `[` is missing and after the `@` the attribute name is also missing. All in all it should be:

```
//select[@name='opcao_pesquisa']
```